# Adding textviews inside Linear layout

Tags: textview, android-linearlayout

How can I do something like this, I have been trying to add texts inside a linearlayout ensuring the second textview in the Linearlayout starts from the end of first textview however I don't know which attributes of xml could solve that. Please help

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Avk5.png)

Comment: Can you show the xml code you have so far and how it looks?